# Unity 2D Trajectory prediction for mobile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, game-engine

I need help with trajectory prediction on mobile.

I'm able to do that on PC using the mouse, but I'm not able to do that with touch functions on mobile.

I've the dot that I copy on the start, and while I'm dragging the ball I want to calculate my trajectory.

After touch will end I will destroy these dots.

As I said I'm able to do it using `Input.GetMouseButton`/Up/Down but I'm not able to do that using touch function.

Here is my code:

```
 private void Update()
{
    //if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    //{


        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            startPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;


            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                trajectoryDots[i] = Instantiate(trajectoryDot, gameObject.transform);

            } 

        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.1f);
            }
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                Destroy(trajectoryDots[i]);
            }

            endPoisiton = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            force = startPosition - endPoisiton;
            ballRigid.gravityScale = 1;
            ballRigid.velocity = new Vector2(force.x * power, force.y * power);

        }

    //}
}

private Vector2 calculatePosition(float elapsedTime)
{

    return new Vector2(endPoisiton.x, endPoisiton.y) +
        new Vector2(force.x * power, force.y * power) * elapsedTime +
        0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * elapsedTime * elapsedTime;


}
```

The code I used for mouse input

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    { //click
        startPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            trajectoryDots[i] = Instantiate(trajectoryDot, gameObject.transform);
        }

    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    { //drag
        endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
        gameObject.transform.position = endPos;
        forceAtPlayer = endPos - startPos;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.1f);
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    { //leave
        rigidbody.gravityScale = 1;
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(-forceAtPlayer.x * forceFactor, -forceAtPlayer.y * forceFactor);
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            Destroy(trajectoryDots[i]);
        }
    }
```

So after little changes it's much better, I' am getting closer to what i want there are still some glitches i guess because of touch.moved so when I' am on display with my finger and do only little moves ball is jumping on the screen 
Here is the code

```
    private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                initPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
                startPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    trajectoryDots[i] = Instantiate(trajectoryDot, gameObject.transform);
                    trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.1f);
                }

                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:

                endPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
                gameObject.transform.position = initPosition;
                force = startPosition - endPosition;
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.1f);
                }
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                ballRigid.gravityScale = 1;
                ballRigid.velocity = new Vector2(force.x * power, force.y * power);

                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    Destroy(trajectoryDots[i]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

private Vector2 calculatePosition(float elapsedTime)
{
    return new Vector2(initPosition.x, initPosition.y) +
    new Vector2(force.x * power, force.y * power) * elapsedTime +
    0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * elapsedTime * elapsedTime;
}
```

Ok i have final soution and it's working correctly

```
    private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                initPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
                startPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    trajectoryDots[i] = Instantiate(trajectoryDot, gameObject.transform);
                    trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.1f);
                }
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                ballRigid.gravityScale = 1;
                ballRigid.velocity = new Vector2(force.x * power, force.y * power);

                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    Destroy(trajectoryDots[i]);
                }
                break;
        }

        endPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
        gameObject.transform.position = initPosition;
        force = startPosition - endPosition;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.1f);
        }
    }
}

private Vector2 calculatePosition(float elapsedTime)
{
    return new Vector2(initPosition.x, initPosition.y) +
    new Vector2(force.x * power, force.y * power) * elapsedTime +
    0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * elapsedTime * elapsedTime;
}
```

Comment: You definitely should keep the `if(Input.touchCount > 0)` otherwise `GetTouch(0)` throws exception while there is no touch. Then rather use a `switch - case` for the touch phase! If you claim it's working for mouse .. could you add the code you use with the mouse input?

Comment: those comments lines yea it was just experimental and i was thinking about switch case too

Answer (score 0):

So just taking your mouse code and convert it to touch code it might look like

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    switch(touch.phase)
    {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            // Note: to be more accurate you actually probably would 
            // rather also here use ScreenToWorldPoint on the touch.position
            // same way as later. Otherwise you might allways get a force even if touch wasn't moved at all
            //startPos = transform.position;
            startPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                trajectoryDots[i] = Instantiate(trajectoryDot, gameObject.transform);
                trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.1f);
            }

           break;

        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            // These were missing in your touch version
            // You did it only in the end so there were no preview trajectory
            // And note that also touch is in pixel screenspace so if you
            // want to use world positions you need to convert them just the same as for mouse input!
            endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
            transform.position = endPos;
            force = endPos - startPos;
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                 trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * 0.1f);
            }
            break;

        case TouchPhase.Ended:
            rigidbody.gravityScale = 1;
            // Not sure why but in your mouse code you used a negative force here 
            // but in this case your trajectory would have been wrong since there you didn't use negative values...
            rigidbody.velocity = force * forceFactor;

            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                Destroy(trajectoryDots[i]);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Btw the calculate method gets better to read like

```
private Vector2 calculatePosition(float elapsedTime)
{  
    return endPoisiton 
        + force * power * elapsedTime 
        + Physics2D.gravity * 0.5f * elapsedTime * elapsedTime;
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: It's not working properly there is some problem with TouchPhase.Moved I guess, I tried it with that too but it's not the same as GetMouseButton, equivalent of GetMouseButton for touch is TouchCount > 0

Comment: Yeah but why would you want to update a trajectory every frame if nothing has changed against the last frame? You would only need to update the trajectory of the finger was actually moved. I therefore would already initialize the positions once in touchpahse.Began (just added this as update)

Comment: Still some problems because touch is working different like MouseButton, Ok i will work on that and i will try to change it

Comment: Thank you for helping i have final solution which is added to my topic

Comment: What do you need `gameObject.transform.position = initPosition;` for? As far as I can see it is not doing anything. Also how is this different to my answer - except the unnecessary trajectory updates when the touch is not moved anyway? ;)

Comment: initPosition is for my ball because i needed ball staying on the same position while i am draging.  Well yea  a little different it's in Touch.Moved that' s all